# MongoMapper - manually setting an ObjectId failing with "illegal ObjectID format"

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

I've got a simple model object:

```
class UserRating
include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument       
key :idea_id, ObjectId
key :rating, Integer
end
```

I'm trying to set an Idea_Id on this object with:
user_rating.idea_id = ObjectId.new

This throws: "illegal ObjectID format"

This sure seems like simple code...  The only oddity I am noticing is that ObjectID != ObjectId.  That could just be a problem with the error message.  Not sure.  Very simple code.  No idea why I can't make it work.  If it helps, this is in the context of a Rails 3 Beta 4 project inside of a Cucumber test.  I am hitting the mongodb daemon successfully, so there's not a weird connection issue.  Would really appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoMapper has a proxy object called ObjectId - in this case, you want a BSON::ObjectID, which represents an ID as it is stored in mongodb itself.

You probably want:

```
key :idea_id, BSON::ObjectID, :index => true
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you want ObjectId. When you assign that you'll want to pass an actual object id which gets generated for each MM model.

user_rating.idea_id = idea.id

Comment: Wow, the man himself!  Thanks for the input John.  In my case, I'm receiving the idea's id from a form post.  I didn't really want to hit mongo just to get an id I already have.  Would it be ok to do something like: 
user_rating.idea_id = Idea.new(:id => params[:idea_id]).id